# What's the more efficient way to solve this matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerics

This is intended to be a more generic question not about a specific system. Given a hermitian matrix $H(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ depending non-linearly on some real parameters $x_1,\dots,x_n$. We want these to be determined numerically such that 
$$H=0$$
and assume we already know that a set of parameters always exists such that this holds.

Would it be more efficient to directly solve the above equation or to optimise its Frobenius norm $||H||_F^2$ (which would just be a scalar)? Also, which method would you apply?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're solving for? It looks as though you're seeking the zero matrix.

Comment: @Richard Indeed, solve for $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that $H$ vanishes.

Comment: How is that different from setting all of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ to zero?

Comment: It really doesn't matter that you have a matrix -- you could just think of a matrix as a vector with funnily-arranged entries. So this is no different to solving the vector equation $\vec F(\vec x)=0$, which is always done using a Newton method (or variants thereof).

Comment: Optimize the Frobenius norm might be a bad idea since the objective function can have local extrema that are different from zero.